# ASR1002 - bootflash

Tags: cisco, router, cisco-asr

Refurbished ASR1002 not booting due to these problems:
It got to ROMMON this far.
How do I go from cleaning to getting this to some random image so that I can desperately upgrade image?
Thanks.

```
rommon 14 > dir bootflash:
Warning: filesystem is not clean
File System: EXT2/EXT3

11         16384     drwx------     lost+found
32385      4096      drwxr-xr-x     core
420993     4096      drwxrwxrwx     .prst_sync
80961      4096      drwxr-xr-x     .rollback_timer
12         0         -rw-------     tracelogs.584
388609     36864     drwxrwxrwx     tracelogs
518145     4096      drwxrwxrwx     .installer
13         383648104 -rw-r--r--     asr1002x-universalk9.03.07.01.S.152-4.S1.SPA.bin
19         3136      -rw-r--r--     TEA_LISP_NOVRF
15         7371      -rw-r--r--     KGLNS
16         7371      -rw-r--r--     KGLNS_WORKIN
113345     4096      drwxr-xr-x     FT
48578      2412      -rw-r--r--     startup-config
48579      869710    -rw-r--r--     KP_PR2650_IMIX.cfg
14         383658280 -rw-r--r--     asr1002x-universalk9.BLD_V152_4_S_XE37_THROTTLE_LATEST_20120810_070021.SSA.bin
17         1529      -rw-r--r--     basic_confg
18         3363      -rw-r--r--     TEA_LISP_VRF
20         1793      -rw-r--r--     basic
22         17        -rw-r--r--     LISP-MapCache-IPv4-00000000-00100
21         53796     -rw-r--r--     reload.log
23         121       -r--r--r--     debug.conf
129537     4096      drwxr-xr-x     .ssh
rommon 15 > boot system bootflash:asr1002x-universalk9.03.07.01.S.152-4.S1.SPA.bin
boot: unsupported boot device "system"
rommon 16 > boot ?
boot: unsupported boot device "?"
rommon 17 > 


monitor: command "" not found


rommon 18 > boot bootflash:asr1002x-universalk9.03.07.01.S.152-4.S1.SPA.bin



Image validated
%IOSXEBOOT-4-FILESYS_ERRORS_CORRECTED: (rp/0): bootflash 1 contained errors which were auto-corrected.
%IOSXEBOOT-4-FILESYS_ERRORS_CORRECTED: (rp/0): bootflash 5 contained errors which were auto-corrected.
%IOSXEBOOT-4-FILESYS_ERRORS_CORRECTED: (rp/0): bootflash 6 contained errors which were auto-corrected.
%IOSXEBOOT-4-FILESYS_ERRORS_CORRECTED: (rp/0): bootflash 7 contained errors which were auto-corrected.
%IOSXEBOOT-4-FILESYS_ERRORS_CORRECTED: (rp/0): bootflash 8 contained errors which were auto-corrected.
%IOSXEBOOT-4-FILESYS_ERRORS_CORRECTED: (rp/0): bootflash 9 contained errors which were auto-corrected.
%IOSXEBOOT-4-FILESYS_ERRORS_CORRECTED: (rp/0): bootflash 10 contained errors which were auto-corrected.
%IOSXEBOOT-4-FILESYS_ERRORS_CORRECTED: (rp/0): bootflash 11 contained errors which were auto-corrected.
%IOSXEBOOT-4-DEVICE_MISSING: (rp/0): Integrity check for missing device /dev/harddisk not performed.
%IOSXEBOOT-4-BOOT_ACTIVITY_LONG_TIME: (rp/0): prep_storage took: 41 seconds, expected max time 10 seconds
%IOSXEBOOT-4-HARDDISK_MISSING: (rp/0): harddisk: not present, boot process continuing
%IOSXEBOOT-4-BOOT_PARAMETER: (rp/0): Booting with custom BOOT_PARAM setting
%IOSXEBOOT-4-DEBUG_CONF: (rp/0): Using DEBUG_CONF file /bootflash/debug.conf
%IOSXEBOOT-4-WATCHDOG_DISABLED: (rp/0): Hardware watchdog timer disabled: disabled by PVP_IGN_CRITICAL_PROC_DOWN
%IOSXEBOOT-4-SR_INIT_SHELL: (rp/0): Router waiting for interactive input for prechasfsinit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the config register, then reset to boot up with the image on the device, ignoring the startup-config:

```
rommon 1 > confreg 0x2142

rommon 2 > reset
```

Once you have it booted up, you can load any image for which you have purchased a license from Cisco.

Comment: stuck at "%IOSXEBOOT-4-SR_INIT_SHELL: (rp/0): Router waiting for interactive input for prechasfsinit"  any idea? is this hardware problem? Thank you

Comment: That is possible. Since you want to update the IOS image, you will want to purchase SMARTnet, which will allow you to consult with Cisco TAC and get it fixed, if necessary.